# Selecting 2 date sets from the same dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a query that selects all the sales from the past 90 days. I want to be able to isolate certain rows on a case/when basis, and can't quite figure out how to do this. The case statement is depending on dates, so: If the date falls between 3/1 and 5/31, then I want to select the sales from any month ends (3/31, 4/30, 5/31 and TODAY) otherwise, if the date is not between 3/1 and 5/31, then I just want to select the past 3 month-ends.

What I tried so far is inserting a Case/When statement in the WHERE clause, but that doesn't seem kosher. Is there another way to go about this?

For reference, the @monthends table contains the following single column:

monthends

- 2019-03-31
- 2019-02-28
- 2019-01-31

and the @insideRule table contains similarly:

insiderRule

- 2019-03-31
- 2019-04-22

The query:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM mytable
   WHERE asofdate IN 
     CASE WHEN asofdate BETWEEN '3-1-2019' AND '5-31-2019' THEN
       (SELECT * FROM @insideRule)
     ELSE
       (SELECT * FROM @monthends)
     END
```

When I execute the above, I get syntax errors around "IN"

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- especially  more information about `asofdate`.

Comment: Because IN requires the use of parens     IN ( ... )

Answer (score 0):

You want `exists` not `case` expression  :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE aasofdate BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-05-31')
   SELECT *
   FROM @insideRule
   ELSE 
   SELECT * 
   FROM @monthends
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you want something like this:

```
SELECT ir.*
FROM @insideRule ir
WHERE getdate() >= '2019-03-01' AND
      getdate() < '2019-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT me.*
FROM @monthends me
WHERE getdate() < '2019-03-01' OR
      getdate() >= '2019-06-01';
```

This assumes that the two tables have the same columns in the same order with compatible types.